# MySQL double join / pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pivot-table

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19c2d/2)

---

I have a table, **inventory** that has some data that looks like this:

```
 +--------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| pmkInventory | fnkPart | inventoryYear | inventoryNum | inventoryR | inventoryC |
+--------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|            1 |      51 |          2016 |            6 | A          |          4 |
|            2 |    2075 |          2016 |           40 | C          |          4 |
|            3 |      50 |          2016 |            3 | A          |          8 |
|            4 |       3 |          2016 |          600 | F          |          3 |
|            5 |       3 |          2017 |          650 | F          |          3 |
|            6 |     100 |          2016 |            2 | B          |          1 |
|            7 |      50 |          2017 |            5 | A          |          8 |
|            8 |      51 |          2017 |           16 | A          |          4 |
+--------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

It has count and location information for each part, each year. There will be more than 2 years (not just 2016 and 2017 stored) but I only need to display two years at a time.

I need to come up with a SQL statement to return something like this:

```
+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| fnkPart | inventoryYear | inventoryNum | inventoryR | inventoryC | inventoryYear | inventoryNum | inventoryR | inventoryC |
+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|      51 | 2016          | 6            | A          | 4          | 2017          | 16           | A          | 4          |
|    2075 | 2016          | 40           | C          | 4          | NULL          | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       |
|      50 | 2016          | 3            | A          | 8          | 2017          | 5            | A          | 8          |
|       3 | 2016          | 600          | F          | 3          | 2017          | 650          | F          | 3          |
|     100 | 2016          | 2            | B          | 1          | NULL          | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       |
|      40 | NULL          | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | NULL          | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       |
|     504 | NULL          | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       | NULL          | NULL         | NULL       | NULL       |
+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

From my reading it sounds like I need some sort of Pivot table, and because MySQL doesn't have a built in one, I will need to use `CASE` statements. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) talks about pivot tables, but I'm confused how to use it without using the `count` function. I don't need to count anything as I have the data already stored in the  database - I just need to display it.

---

A non pivot-table solution I came up with sort of works. It correctly shows the years, but doesn't show rows with null values. I have a part table with thousands of parts. I'm joining the inventory table to it. I thought that by doing a `LEFT JOIN` I would get all the parts, even if there wasn't data for the specified years in the inventory table.

Here is that:

```
SELECT p.pmkPart, p.partNumber, 
       i1.fnkPart, i1.inventoryYear, i1.inventoryNum, i1.inventoryR, i1.inventoryC, 
       i2.fnkPart, i2.inventoryYear, i2.inventoryNum, i2.inventoryR, i2.inventoryC
FROM part AS p
LEFT JOIN inventory as i1
       ON p.pmkPart = i1.fnkPart
LEFT JOIN inventory as i2
       ON p.pmkPart = i2.fnkPart
WHERE i1.inventoryYear = 2016
AND i2.inventoryYear = 2017
GROUP BY p.pmkPart
```

This query would give me something like this. Notice it's missing part `2075` and `100` because they do not values for the year 2017. It is also excluding the rest of the parts from the `part` table - that have no values in the `inventory` table.

```
+---------+------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
| pmkPart | partNumber | fnkPart | inventoryYear | inventoryNum | inventoryR | inventoryC | fnkPart | inventoryYear | inventoryNum | inventoryR | inventoryC |
+---------+------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|      51 | AB-l34     |      51 |          2016 |            6 | A          |          4 |      51 |          2017 |           16 | A          |          4 |
|      50 | AB-l36     |      50 |          2016 |            3 | A          |          8 |      50 |          2017 |            5 | A          |          8 |
|       3 | C-5-BT     |       3 |          2016 |          600 | F          |          3 |       3 |          2017 |          650 | F          |          3 |
+---------+------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+---------+---------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

---

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can modify my existing query to get the correct result? Or how to create a pivot table that does what I want?

The years I'm selecting I need to be able to change, but I will only be selecting two at a time, 2016 and 2017, or 2016 and 2018, or 2017 and 2018, etc.

I've figured out how to do this using a combination of `php` and `MySQL`, but I am moving to a new platform where server side scripting is not an option, so need to move everything into SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the year condition to the join itself:

```
SELECT p.pmkPart, p.partNumber, 
       i1.fnkPart, i1.inventoryYear, i1.inventoryNum, i1.inventoryR, i1.inventoryC, 
       i2.fnkPart, i2.inventoryYear, i2.inventoryNum, i2.inventoryR, i2.inventoryC
FROM part AS p
LEFT JOIN inventory as i1
       ON p.pmkPart = i1.fnkPart
       AND i1.inventoryYear = 2016
LEFT JOIN inventory as i2
       ON p.pmkPart = i2.fnkPart
       AND i2.inventoryYear = 2017
```

Also, there's no aggregate in this query, so you don't need to group by anything.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I didn't remember it was possible to put a "where" in a join.